# Spring Boot Filter with form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, filter, multipartform-data

The actual request is with a Content-Type application/json then the request will go to filter to be modify, change the Content-Type to `multipart/form-data` then add a hardcoded key and value as a `form-data` but my current set up is not working. Any idea?

```
public class LogRequestResponseFilter implements Filter {

   

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;


       
            
            ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
            ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);

//            MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) wrappedRequest;
//            multipartRequest.getParameterMap().put("scope", new String[]{"read"});

            filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, responseWrapper);

            String responseBody = getStringValue(responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray(),servletResponse.getCharacterEncoding());

            generateTokenUriLog(responseBody,httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse);
            responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
```

Error
This is the error if im going to uncomment this code

`MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) wrappedRequest;`

`multipartRequest.getParameterMap().put("scope", new String[]{"read"});`

```
class org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper cannot be cast to class org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest
```

Comment: You have to either add `@Component` to your filter or add it programatically inside your `SecurityFilterChain`.

Comment: Hai @Slevin its already has the `@Component` but the problem is about the hardcoded form-data as a request

Comment: *is not working* is not an error description. Please explain what it means

Comment: @Jens i want to modify the incoming request with a hard coded value in form-data by using filter

Comment: That I understood. But what *is not working*? Do you get any error message, the request does not hit the filter ....

Comment: @Jens This is the error when i try to uncomment the 2 line as showed at code above
`class org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper cannot be cast to class org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest`
The error is about cast, im still looking for a right code for form-data

Comment: Then please add this important information to the question

Comment: @Jens Sure, I have updated it

Answer (score 0):

another approach is to use

```
public void somefunction(@ModelAttribute FormData formdata){}
```

in your controller where (FormData) is your object containing all of your form data